# connect google drive folder to google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I need to load all image in google colab from google drive folder

The path of google drive folder:
My Drive > Data Science > Deep_learning > dogImages > train > Yorkshire_terrian> Yorkshire_terrian01.pnj

#dogImages is main folder in which there are three sub folder train, test, valid and in each sub folder there are folder for different bog breed and in that dog breed folder there are images

#now I want to store all images which are there in different folder in one variable nmae "dog_breed_image"

can anyone tell me how to do that

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

upload entire folder "dog_breed_image" in your google drive.

then mount your google drive to the colab

once your drive mount with the colab you can access your folder and as per requirement you can access your file inside folder and sub-folder by their path(i.e copy path).